# Prototype menu

Tags: menu, prototypejs

Does anyone know of a good javascript menu using the prototype library. 
I need to produce a list of links available for each row of a HTML table as a hover/click dropdown menu.

**Constraints**

- The list of links is the same for every row, however, a link needs to post an id param unique to the row.
- The table is in a scroll pane, so the menu needs to know if if should render itself on the other side of the associated HTML element (e.g. **TD**) if necessary for visiblity.

I've found some a nice plugin for the JQuery library, but don't currently use JQuery and would like to avoid adding it if possible. I am already using prototype 1.6.

Comment: A context menu, displayed when user clicks on a record, and preferably smart enough to move around the target element so the menu's bounds are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the blog post below has used prototype to create a drop-down JS menu.  I don't think it fits the bill for everything you're looking for, but it should give you a starting point.

http://www.blog.highub.com/javascript/javascript-library/prototype-drop-down-menu/

Comment: I saw that one in the google results, and isn't really what I was looking for. I need an efficient dhtml menu that will position relative to a clicked element.